# Javac error: Cannot find Symbol

Tags: java, javac

I had programmed several programs and I had compiled some of them, but know I have programmed a Chat messenger. And when I compile the Server or the Client I always get an error from javac. "error: cannot find symbol". And by both the error is at the constructor of other class how should construct there.
example:

```
Chat.java:11  error: cannot find symbol
                       Frame frm = new Frame();
                                       ^
Symbol:   class Frame
location: class Chat
Chat.java:11  error: cannot find symbol
                       Frame frm = new Frame();
                       ^
Symbol:   class Frame
location: class Chat
```

MAIN

```
package main;

public class Chat {

public static void main(String args[]){

    Frame frm = new Frame();

    frm.setLayout(null);
    frm.setVisible(true);
    frm.setSize(800, 600);
    frm.setResizable(false);
    // a loop who wait for an true boolean
    frm.abfrage();

    while(true){
        frm.readChat();
    }
}

}
```

FRAME Class without Functions(only Constructor)

```
package main;

//action + windowlistener + event import;

//Inputreader,writer,reader and IOException import;

//socket import + exception;

//.. there are some Javax.swing imports;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

Client client;

JPanel textPanel;
static boolean start;
static JTextArea messengerText;
JTextField writenText;
JTextField portInfo;
JTextField hostInfo;
JButton senden;
JButton connect;

public String writenString;
public String chatString;
int port;
String adress;

public Frame(){
    super("Chat by lionlak");

//      this.client = client;

    client = new Client("localhost",5483);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    //Deklarationen
    start = false;
    writenString = "Hallo vom Client";
    chatString = "Chat by lionlak";

    //Konstruktoren
      //JPanel
    textPanel = new JPanel();
      //JTextField
    writenText = new JTextField();
    portInfo = new JTextField();
    hostInfo = new JTextField();

    messengerText = new JTextArea();
      //JButton
    senden = new JButton("SENDEN");
    connect = new JButton("Connect");
    //Listener
    senden.addActionListener(new actionListener());
    connect.addActionListener(new actionListener());

    addWindowListener(new windowHandler());

    //Eigenschaften
      //JPanel
    textPanel.setLayout(null);
    textPanel.setBounds(10,150,490,780);
      //JTextField
    portInfo.setBounds(120,10,100,40);
    portInfo.setText("5483");
    hostInfo.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 40);
    hostInfo.setText("127.0.0.1");
    messengerText.setBounds(0,0,380,290);
    messengerText.setText(chatString);
    writenText.setBounds(0, 310, 280, 100);
    writenText.setText("Deine Nachricht!");
      //JButton
    senden.setBounds(290, 310, 100, 40);
    connect.setBounds(230, 10, 100, 40);

    //Add
    textPanel.add(messengerText);
    textPanel.add(writenText);
    textPanel.add(senden);
    add(hostInfo);
    add(portInfo);
    add(connect);
    add(textPanel);
}
```

Comment: import java.awt.Frame;

Comment: You need to include more information. For instance, the code that uses `Frame`. At the moment, most people assume you are referring to `java.awt.Frame` however it is possible that you are not.

Comment: my recommendation is: use an IDE like Eclipse, it would help. and, obviously, study enough Java to understand the basis.

Comment: I use an IDE normaly, but I want to make it runable for an friend. And I know the Java basics,else couldn't programmed something like that.But sure I don't know so much like the people who are registered here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Chat.java you are referencing your own Frame.class which lies in the same package. So there is no need for an import.

But the Frame.class has to be accessible to the Compiler, either by adding it to the classpath of the compiler or better by compiling all of your java files in a single compile call.
For example:

```
javac Frame.java Chat.java
```

One problem might be if the Frame.java has compilation errors that prevents it from compiling so that there is no Frame.class.

Comment: they said that I had to import this,also is this false ? And and how can I had the classpath or how can I compile all in one call ? with javac *.java ? Because when I am compile it with javac *.java and then try to start it,then I get a NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: If you want to use your own Frame.class, then you must not import any other Frame.class, otherwise the system will use the wrong one. When I learned Java in 1996, I used to compile with javac *.java, but long time ago I switched to using IDE like eclipse or netbeans. Therefore I'm not sure if there were some changes when compiling with javac on the commandline. As logoff already mentioned it a comment to the question, I would also recommend to use an IDE since it eliminates these kind of technical problems (but may introduce other problems)

Comment: I use the IDE,but I want to make it runable for an friend,because this is for him.So how can I make it runable for other people ?

Comment: @AlexanderKnotek "To make it runnable for a friend" - what do you mean with this phrase: a) your friend should be able to compile the classes or b) your friend should be able to run the compiled classes with java main.Chat? If b), then you can use the IDE and just export the compiled classes as a jar file.

Comment: @ the downvoter: may I ask for the reason of the downvote since I see no comment with an explanation here?

Comment: I don't give the down vote.I can't do this. I want that my friend can use my programm whitout do anything . So that I make this finish for him and he can use it. This a chat programm and I don't want to chat with myself :D . And I tried export but how can I start the .jar file. Because I tried with cmd command java Chat and java Chat.java

Comment: @AlexanderKnotek if all of the classes and resources are inside a jar file named chat.jar, u could use 'java -cp chat.jar main.Chat' to start your chat

Comment: Okay I will try when I'm back at home and tell you if its work :) , but thank you very much ,because I don't know very much about that commands :)

Comment: But there is actually still another problem. Because if I start it over this,my Server start and works like I start it in IDE,but My Client only send,but don't get the message.But in IDE it works normal.

Comment: A last Question! If I start my Client with this command, my Frame and Buttons don't react in the Frame,but I can connect to Server. I think he don't updates the Frame or something like that! But in IDE it works. What can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: "compiling all of your classes in a single compile call." - this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following import line at the beginning of your file:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
```

Depending on your tastes, and if you use other classes in the `java.awt` package, you may want to use this:

```
import java.awt.*;
```

Comment: maybe a dumb question,but when I import this,how can I call functions from Frame then?

Comment: You don't need to change anything. All you need is to add the import line. You can then call `Frame` functions without changing anything.

Comment: @AlexanderKnotek `Frame` is a class which resides in `java.awt` package. When you say `Frame frm = new Frame();`, that means your creating instance of Frame class. and through that instance you can call the methods available.

Comment: Did you try the import? also, which frame do you want here?

Comment: @AlexanderKnotek check out my answer.  There are a lot of helpful links.  Hopefully it clarifies things.

Comment: @AlexanderKnotek Do you have `Frame.java` class defined in your package somewhere? and I really dont get waht do you mean by `the error by compiling is by the functions of frame `

Comment: when I import java.awt.Frame then eclipse say that the methode .. is undefined for the type Frame

Comment: where should I import this file ? In my Main or in my Frame class? Because when I am importing at main class,then there is an error by the methods of Frame and by Frame it complicateds whit java.swing.JFrame.

Comment: You are using your own class named `Frame`? You need to import that class instead, from main.

Comment: Yes, I use my own Class Frame. And now i should Import this Class in Main?

Comment: -1 since import of java.awt.Frame is not the solution since he wants to use his own Frame.class

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are saying to import `java.awt.Frame`, however, there could be some other `Frame` class which you need to import. This `Frame` class will belong to the API package you are trying to compile against.

Comment: the problem is when I'm iport java.awt.Frawe than my methode get an error! The methode is undefine for the type frame

Comment: Yes, I know, don't do that. You need a different `Frame` class.